# TypeError: record.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I recive an array

```
{AccountID: "00s",
 Name: "Lna da", 
 ID: "001c000001vMEp4AAG", 
 users: [
      0: {Name: "Leana Fonda", ID: "003c000001LUh4IAAT", email: null}
      1: {Name: "Peter Fonda", ID: "003c000001Ka5fQAAR", email: null}
      2: {Name: "chris fonda", ID: "003c000001Ka5v4AAB", email: null}
 ]
}
```

I was doing this one before

```
      selectedRowStack.push(record.users);
result: 
 [Array(9)]
```

and for 2nd array  another  result will be

```
 [Array(9), Array(6)] or 
0: (9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
1: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

I want users array  only and and it to array as single dimension of array of objects.that's why Im doing this one

```
          selectedRowStack.push(record.map(res=>res.users).flat());
```

but it throws error please help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you wish to take the 'users' array from multiple 'account' objects and add all users to a single array. In this case, you are looking for the `Array.prototype.concat` method:

```
selectedRowStack = selectedRowStack.concat(record.users)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: Concat can only return an empty array if both `selectedRowStack` and `record.users` are empty.

Comment: Note that concat does not mutate arrays so you MUST assign the result ie. `selectedRowStack = selectedRowStack.concat(record.users)`, not just `selectedRowStack.concat(record.users)`

Answer (score 0):

If using latest JS version, try flatMap for this purpose

```js
a =[
    {AccountID: "00s",
 Name: "Lna da", 
 ID: "001c000001vMEp4AAG", 
 users: [
      {Name: "Leana Fonda", ID: "003c000001LUh4IAAT", email: null},
      {Name: "Peter Fonda", ID: "003c000001Ka5fQAAR", email: null},
      {Name: "chris fonda", ID: "003c000001Ka5v4AAB", email: null},
 ]
},
{AccountID: "00s",
 Name: "Lna da", 
 ID: "001c000001vMEp4AAG", 
 users: [
      {Name: "Leana Fonda", ID: "003c000001LUh4IAAT", email: null},
      {Name: "Peter Fonda", ID: "003c000001Ka5fQAAR", email: null},
      {Name: "chris fonda", ID: "003c000001Ka5v4AAB", email: null},
 ]
}
] 

a.flatMap(a => a.users);
```